# A higher badge than the gold badge: How about introducing platinum or diamond badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, rarest-badges

Reasons why:

- Many gold badges are reached pretty fast therefore badges like this
  may increase motivation for further participation in the site
- Higher badges may be awarded for really exceptional and outstanding achievements or support in a certain area

Some examples where this would be useful:

- Review Queues with more than 5 K or 10 K reviews so reviewers do not stop at the magical 1000
- Tag Badges: 5 K or more upvotes in a certain area of expertise
- Very famous questions with more than 100 K views

Just an idea. What do you think about it? Great or terrible?

Comment: Is there a problem with people stopping participating in the site once they have earned gold badges?

Comment: Of course not. Nobody is on stackoverflow for just the badges. However it could be a nice motivation.

Comment: John Skeet's flair already has trouble holding up just measly three categories of badges. If you give her more, the poor thing is going to explode. Why won't anyone think of the flairs. :(

Comment: Also note: we want people to review because they want to contribute reviews, **not** because they can earn yet another badge. We don't need more robo-reviewers.

Comment: Will somebody really do 5 K reviews for a badge? Or will it motivate a great reviewer to review further?

Comment: I really don't see the need here.  Sure there are some "easy" gold badges to get but the ones that really count are tough to get.

Comment: I'd like to have a _granite_ badge for my continuous stubborness!

Comment: Well I assime that the basic consent is that another badge is not needed :-)

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but I'm not here for the badges, or the reps. I'm here for the hats.

Comment: the *gamification* of knowledge sharing is already the worst thing about this site, dont make it even worse.

Comment: @Blackbam People do 1000 reviews for a badge, why wouldn't they do 5000?

Comment: @rtfm The gamification of knowledge sharing is an essential part of Stackoverflow. Why is it bad? IMHO it increases fun of work.

Comment: @Rob Sure why not? And why not honour their efforts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, we don't need another level of badges. Users that routinely reach gold badges have found *other motivations* to participate. If they are still here for the badges only, we are doing it wrong.

This comes up from time to time, the oldest one I can find is [Platinum Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges) over on the central Meta.

[Jeff Atwood sums it up nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52553/140890):

> Heaping reward on top of reward is not the goal of badges.
>
> **Ideally, new badges explore a different *dimension* of participation**, some behavior that is positive but we don't sufficiently acknowledge yet.

Comment: In that case lets roll out the close vote badges :)

Comment: seems related: [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/165773)