# Can we have a platinum rank of badges?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

I guess it's time to propose a new rank of badges for these guys.

I call it the *platinum* section. I propose a badge in this criteria:

- **Helpful Expert** - reaching out to 100m people (The amount comes from their "~(num) people reached" stats.)

This might not just be Stack Overflow, but maybe even the rest of the SE Network.

So should we bring this special rank of badges into the network? And if so, when?

Comment: Does this actually look like a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a bad idea. Why award badges for reputation? We already award reputation for reputation.

Comment: @CodyGray Now that you mentioned it, I brought it back, but the problem is "meta effect". I could easily get downvotes on my existing questions soon.

Comment: I *hope* that is unlikely. "The Meta effect" refers to when you use Meta to bring attention to one of your posts on the main site, as in by asking, "Is this question eligible for re-opening?" Then, people naturally visit the post in question and vote on it, which can be a double-edged sword. However, posting a completely unrelated feature request or bug report ***really shouldn't*** cause you to get downvotes on any of your posts on the main site. If it does, well, I'm very disappointed in the community, and perhaps you should raise a moderator flag so we can look into who might be involved.

Comment: "*So should we bring this special rank of badges into the network?*" as the person making the feature request it should be you who answers this question and us asking it.

Comment: Related: [A higher badge than the gold badge: How about introducing platinum or diamond badges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351348/2675154)

Comment: I had to explain my votes - which is generally frowned upon - as I could not properly vote on this post as I believe it is poorly researched - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=platinum+badge shows almost identical proposal and does not explain how proposed feature would be beneficial for the site (-1), and as well I disagree that we need such badges (so need another -1)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

People reached is [an extremely stupid and inaccurate metric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped) that tends to jump up and down, a lot. That number means nothing.

Badges are always network wide. AFAIK there are no exceptions to this rule.

In general a badge is designed around a positive action done by you. It is something that is achievable. You can't really control if or how much your answer will contribute to "people reached". There are a few other badges that are designed around statistics rather then positive action, like views and score and those are nice enough.

We don't need more badges at the higher end of the "rewards".